# mongoose Schema max property has no effect

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

```js
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const PostSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    user_id: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    content: {
      type: String,
      max: 150,
      required: true,
    },
  },
  {
    timestamps: true,
  }
);
```

As defined above, I can nevertheless push content that has more than 150 characters. What is wrong with how the Query is defined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Type string does not have “max”, instead use “maxLength”:

```
maxLength: 150,
```

Documentation about [validation](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/validation.html) that mentions this.

Hopefully that helps!